# Viewing list of downloaded apps, in the order they were downloaded

Tags: applications, google-play-store, installation

I am running Android 12 on a Realme 8 5G phone.

How can I view my apps in the order in which I've downloaded them from the Google Play store (instead, of alphabetically, in the phone's app drawer)?

I need this because I would like to go through all the downloaded apps and go through them.

Is there a place where I can download such an operating system enhancement/ window manager enhancement, on Android?

If this cannot be done, then I wonder whether this can be done through a special app that keeps track of downloads, and whereby you can launch apps from it. I wonder if this is possible also for apps that are not launcher apps, but could allow you to open apps by presenting them in a list (is a special "launch apps" permission required for this, I think not). Can the app just retrieve, the app installation time, from the file system (if it cannot determine the order in which the Google Play install button was clicked)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Usually phone OS does not offer this feature. Many third party apps do this.

[APPs history](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.laurentiugh.mylatestapps) is one such app that is simple in it's interface. From the app description

> A list of your applications, last installed shown first. Run or see details

> My Latest Apps shows you an application lists sorted either by the first install or by the last update time so you will not miss any apps when testing time comes!

> You can directly launch applications from the list or go to app's settings in order to stop/uninstall a certain app.

I find it useful to debug changes in Phone's behavior if one of the recently installed apps is causing it.

I am not affiliated with it.

You can also use [`pm list packages/adb dumpsys packsges commands`](https://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=Pm+list) for similar queries.